# Concatenate fasta files in loop

Tags: python, biopython

I have multiple fasta files with multiple individuals with sequences of the same lenght. What I want to do is to create a concatenation of the sequence of species along the fasta files.

In the loop: If one species is found in the next file, I concatenate its sequence, if not, I concatenate gaps ('-'), with the same lenght as the rest of sequences. (See the files are aligned)

```
species_list = []
files = [file for file in glob.glob('~/*.fa')]
for aln in files:
    with open (aln, 'rU') as multispecies:
        sequences = SeqIO.parse(multispecies, 'fasta')
        for species in sequences:
            species_list.append(species.id)

species_list=list(set(species_list))
#print(species_list)

concat = {}
for aln in files:
    #print(aln)
    dict = {}
    with open (aln, 'rU') as multispecies:
        sequences = SeqIO.parse(multispecies, 'fasta')
        names = []
        for fasta in sequences:
            names.append(fasta.id)
            dict[fasta.id] = fasta.seq
        count_species = 0
        for i in species_list:
            if i in names:
                count_species = count_species + 1
                print('>' + i + '\n' + dict[i])
                gap = int(len(dict[i]))
                concat[i] += dict[i]    #I cannot find a way to concatenate here
            else:
                print('>' + i + '\n' + '-'*gap)
                concat[i] += '-'*gap #I cannot find a way to concatenate here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concat should either be a defaultdict or otherwise handle missing keys by creating some flavor of iterable, probably a str or, preferably, a list in this case. Then you can extend the iterable with the new values:

```
# list-based
concat.setdefault(i, []).extend(dict[i]) # should work if you keep the data in a list
# string-based
concat[i] = concat.get(i, '') + dict[i]
```

String-based approach is extremely inefficient though because you have to rebuild the string from the ground up on each concatenation. If you NEED a string, you can always make it a list then " ".join it once you're done building it.

Comment: Good solution, I still dont get why my dictionary concat needs the use of 'get'. It could just add nothing to the dictionary, as the dictionary is being created outside the loop.

Comment: Dicts don't support `__add__` out of the box. You can only use it on the _values_ that do support it (i.e. for a dict1 like {'a' : 2} you can do dict1['a'] += 3, but you cannot do dict2 += {'a' : 3} to add a new item to a empty dict). You cannot assume to know the keys in the dict before you encounter them in the FASTA, so while you could bake in empty lists under appropriate keys, you shouldn't. Hence, *you use 'get' to create a new, empty list* if need arises, and add stuff to it.

Comment: Great, thanks. I partially solve my issue. At first it worked out as I want, but the more I run the code, the different concatenation is given (not only the correct), plus sometimes it does not recognize a variable and sometimes does it. I am wondering if this is because  some bug in my code ..? pretty weird. I checked that I am using python 3.5.2

Comment: I cannot parse what exactly your problem is now. Please provide an example and/or code.